# How to prevent Postgres from deadlocking on concurrent single-row upserts?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out what's causing an issue in an application of mine. The gist of the problem is that the postgres server logs show a deadlock on an upsert query, and I'm not sure why that would happen - I don't have my upserts wrapped in a transaction, and I don't upsert more than 1 row at a time.

My table is structured like this:

```
postgres=> \d test_data_table
         Table "public.test_data_table"
 Column | Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | text  |           | not null | 
 data   | jsonb |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "test_data_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

and the upsert query being run is like this:

```
INSERT INTO test_data_table (id, data)
  VALUES ($1, to_jsonb($2::jsonb))
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO
    UPDATE SET id = $3, data = to_jsonb($4::jsonb);
```

I distilled my problem down to two Java threads just running the upsert query at the same time (using HikariCP + Postgres JDBC driver, if it's relevant). By putting print statements in the code, I can see that only one of the threads is able to finish upserting correctly. When I use the "Сombination of blocked and blocking activity" query from [this Postgres wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) (specifically, the "alternate" version that includes application name), I get the following output:

```
 blocked_pid | blocked_user | blocking_pid | blocking_user |                                                             blocked_statement                                                             |                                                   current_statement_in_blocking_process                                                   |  blocked_application   |  blocking_application  
-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------
        2576 | postgres     |         2575 | postgres      | INSERT INTO test_data_table (id, data)VALUES ($1, to_jsonb($2::jsonb)) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET id = $3, data = to_jsonb($4::jsonb) | INSERT INTO test_data_table (id, data)VALUES ($1, to_jsonb($2::jsonb)) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET id = $3, data = to_jsonb($4::jsonb) | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
(1 row)
```

and at this point, I'm unsure what can be done to deal with this problem effectively.

I have already seen:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366324/postgres-deadlocks-on-concurrent-upserts), which I don't *think* is applicable, as my use-case is only upserting one row at a time.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964616/postgres-deadlock) which I believe is not applicable for the same reason as the first one.

Comment: *" I don't have my upserts wrapped in a transaction"* Does not matter *"PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it. A group of statements surrounded by BEGIN and COMMIT is sometimes called a transaction block."* [source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html)

Comment: `Column | Type | id   | text  ` i wonder why you would need to use a text datatype as id column can you explain that?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am aware of this - I say that I didn't explicitly wrap them in a transaction mainly so that there is no doubt that I'm doing something like forgetting to commit a transaction

Comment: `text` is used as the column datatype mainly for the sake of testing, and because I wanted a string key of variable length so I wouldn't have to think about my data as carefully. Additionally, the postgres wiki seems to suggest using text instead of varchar(n) https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Text_storage